# Easiest or Best Free Way to Scan to PDF in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, scanner

I have a scanner (part of an HP PSC 1315 multifunction printer, if that makes any difference).  I've recently paved my Windows XP machine and appear to have lost the software for the printer.  This has meant that I have to use Windows Image Acquisition or Microsoft Word to scan images and documents.

The main problem that I have with this scenario is that WIA only scans to images, not to PDF, and I would prefer to have my documents scanned to PDF (the HP software scanned to PDF and 
did OCR as well).  I haven't actually used the Word integration (as I'd prefer not to have Word fully installed), but I'm open to using it if it can help me.  I have Word 2002/XP available.

I'm not really interested in finding a solution enough to have to buy something.

So, **are there any free utilities for Windows XP which will let me scan to PDF?**  Extra points for OCR, great software, or ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

if you're happy with the HP software for your scanner, you can download the [**Officejet and PSC Full Feature Software**](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=mp-23606-2&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ie&product=374568&os=228&lang=en) (364 MB) from the HP support website.

other than that, you can print to to PDF from ANY application with a PDF printer driver (e.g. [**CutePDF**](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp))

and here's a list of [**Free OCR Software Dowloads**](http://www.freeocr.net/), take your pick :)

Comment: I used the Full Software install of the printer, and unless it's hiding it from me, there's still no scanning software on my machine.

Comment: well, this us the software bundled on the driver disc. do you by any chance remember the actual name of the feature or program you have been using before?

Comment: I think it all fell under the title of HP Director.

Comment: and HP Director is NOT included in the software bundle? strange. anyway, as a workaround you can always scan a document (with WIA or the HP interface), print the image as PDF with Cute PDF and/or run the image through your OCR software.